# Kendo UI with ASP.NET MVC3 default values when adding row to grid

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui

I am converting an existing app from Telerik MVC extensions to the newer KendoUI product.  I am using the grid control.  How do I specify the default values for the columns when adding a new row to the grid?

With the old Telerik MVC extensions, I did the following:

```
.Editable(editing=>editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DefaultDataItem(Model.defaultItem))
```

The defaultItem of my model was my default for added rows.  So how do I do this with Kendo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yo yo yo mate,

You need to specify default value for each of the fields via the dataSource model configuration

Here is an example you can use ;)

```
@(Html.Kendo()
.Grid<TestModel>()
.Name("SomeOtherGridName")
.DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Read("test", "test").Model(
    x => {
        x.Field(c => c.Val1).DefaultValue(5);
        x.Field(c => c.Val2).DefaultValue("cool!");
    }
 ))
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Val1);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Val2);
})
)
```

Answer (score 0):

DefaultDataItem [does not currently exist](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/replacement-for-defaultdataitem.aspx) in the MVC extensions specifically. However, it is still possible [without using the MVC extensions](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#model.define) as a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension method that accomplishes the core functionality of `DefaultDataItem()`. It reads every property of a default item and sets the `Field()` and `DefaultValue()` in the data source model definition:

```
public static class DataSourceModelDescriptorFactoryExtensions
{
    public static DataSourceModelDescriptorFactory<TModel> DefaultDataItem<TModel>(
        this DataSourceModelDescriptorFactory<TModel> dataSourceModelBuilder,
        TModel defaultDataItem) where TModel : class
    {
        var propertyInfos = typeof(TModel).GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            dataSourceModelBuilder
                .Field(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.PropertyType)
                .DefaultValue(propertyInfo.GetValue(defaultDataItem));
        }

        return dataSourceModelBuilder;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyEntity>()
    ...
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        ...
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(n => n.Id);
            model.DefaultDataItem(myDefaultEntity);
        }
    )
)
```